# Is there any alternative to Permission sets?

Tags: profile, permission-sets

Is there any alternative to permission sets in salesforce to give extra privileges to the users of the same profile?

Comment: Not really no. What is the problem with using permission sets? The other alternatives can be doing things with Sharing rules and groups but that is for record access rather than privileges.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE. Your question doesn't have enough detail to get a real answer. I suspect this may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info). Consider making an [edit] describing what you're trying to do, and why it's not working. We'll be able to better answer your question that way.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Love the x-y problem. You always have great little tidbits. The linked doc is good too: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

Permission sets do not have any special permissions that a profile does not.

Permission sets are used to give profile permissions to a specific user without having to create a profile separately for that user.

Your question as it is written

> Is there any alternative to permission sets in salesforce to give
>   extra privileges to the users of the same profile

I take it that you have a significant number of users requiring the permission set but not every user of that profile correct?

**The answer would be Yes, set the permission on the profile itself.**

If you have only part of the users of that profile that require the permissions, you may want to think about creating a profile specifically for them. Only you can determine if the number of users requiring the permissions is significant enough to warrant a new specific profile.

Sometimes we overthink things. If a new profile makes sense then don't be afraid to do it just because we have permission sets.